# CANVAS HTML5 - Problema al mostrar dos elementos en el lienzo

Tags: html5, canvas

### Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en el lienzo un fondo degradado y luego mostrar un texto.

**El código es el siguiente:**

```html
<canvas id="canv" height="720" width="1280">
            Su navegador no es compatible con CANVAS, use otro navegador
</canvas>
```

```js
function Start() {
    // Genera un área de trabajo
    var elemento = document.getElementById("canv");
    canv = elemento.getContext("2d"); // Especifica entorno

    // Degradado
    gradiente = canv.createLinearGradient(0,0,1280,720);
    gradiente.addColorStop(0,"#f58080");
    gradiente.addColorStop(1,"#8b0e0e");
    canv.fillStyle = gradiente;  // Muestra gradiente
    canv.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);


    // Texto
    // canv.beginPath();
    canv.font = "bold 24px verdana";
    canv.textAlign = "start"; // Espeficia alineación
    canv.fillText("Texto",200,200);
}
Start();
```

El problema radica en que al ejecutar se logra ver que aparece el texto por unos minisegundos y luego aparece el fondo degradado tapa el texto

[image]

**Basicamente el fondo tapa el texto**

**Si borro el codigo de mostrar fondo degradado, como es de esperarse solo aparece el TEXTO**

[image]

Se que estoy haciendo algo mal, estuve buscando pero no logro solucionarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este momento estás llenando el texto con el mismo degradados de antes. Por esto que no lo ves. Añade `canv.fillStyle = "black";` (o el color que tu quieras) justo antes de `canv.fillText("Texto",200,200);`

```js
function Start() {
    // Genera un área de trabajo
    var elemento = document.getElementById("canv");
    canv = elemento.getContext("2d"); // Especifica entorno

    // Degradado
    gradiente = canv.createLinearGradient(0,0,1280,720);    gradiente.addColorStop(0,"#f58080");    gradiente.addColorStop(1,"#8b0e0e");
    canv.fillStyle = gradiente;  // Muestra gradiente
    canv.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);


    // Texto
    // canv.beginPath();
    canv.font = "bold 24px verdana";
    canv.textAlign = "start"; // Espeficia alineación
    
    //Establece el color del texto
    canv.fillStyle = "black"; 
  
  
    canv.fillText("Texto",200,200);
}
Start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" height="720" width="1280">
            Su navegador no es compatible con CANVAS, use otro navegador
</canvas>
```